# Two edit suggestions rejected, then one "stolen". Please, verify

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I run into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10923111/1469208). I found most of its body completely off-topic. OP spends four or five lines, entire first paragraph, to talk about configuration issues, he *had already resolved*, only to ask, how he can add or change comment for MySQL table or column.

Since I got no bloody idea, what setting up phpMyAdmin and changing its configuration have to do with setting or changing table or column comment, I've [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4187350) to remove entire first paragraph.

It was nearly immediately rejected with comment:

> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.

I'm still convinced, that entire paragraph is completely off-topic, but I agreed with most of the reviewers decision and [suggested another edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4187470), where I left much more of the original text.

It was also nearly immediately rejected, with three reviewers replying:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

After another few seconds I found out, that though my review was rejected, question now have the text, that I proposed in second edit suggestion, only marked as... edited by *[jamesj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368186/jamesj)*.

I'm completely lost! Can someone explain me, please, what is going on:

1. When I'm only **removing** large parts of original text, but I'm **not adding anything** (or nearly anything) on my own, how can someone treat such edit as "*an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post*"?
2. When did we I start to play in edit-steals in SE? How can three reviewers reject my edit and then one of them come in and make "an edit" that is about 99% or even 100% the same as my suggested one -- only all the credits goes to him?

I don't care for that spare two points for making an edit! I made over 80 edits so far an none of them was for reputation, only for making SE even better. But such situation, as above, does piss me off a little bit.

Comment: They are two separate parts of the sentence: *This edit is incorrect* **or** *an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post*.

Comment: Gosh! Didn't I make enough clear, that I don't care for the reputation, so let's cut this part off, right? Your comments does not answer the key question. I'm just curious, how can three different, separate reviewers all together mark, that edit is incorrect, if I only removed some words? Previous comment to edit rejection was much more meaningful. `This edit is incorrect` says nothing and any reviewer can virtually mark this to any edit, he or she "doesn't like". I'm surprised, that such meaningless flag exists.

Answer (score 8):

For your second suggestion, you can see that *jamesj* wanted to approve your edit while also improving it further.

Unfortunately, this user was too late and your edit was already rejected. This caused *jamesj* to sort of become the author of your edit too. They did not steal your edit on purpose.

Comment: I don't know, where I can see this? I only see (below edited text and in edit suggestion summary), that he has edited this question. I don't know about what kind of improvement you're talking about, if "his" text is about 99% the same as mine (or I'm really, really bind or tired)?